# Precise sleeping time with ESP32

Tags: esp32

I want to write a code that wakes up ESP32 every round 10 minutes (such as, 10:00, 10:10, 10:20, 10:30...). The code then does some tasks, calculates the time until the next round 10 minutes and sends ESP32 to sleep. The last part of the code is below:

```
#include "time.h"

uint64_t currenttime;
uint64_t sleeptime;

currenttime = static_cast<uint64_t> (time(nullptr));
sleeptime = (600 - (currenttime % 600));          // time to the next round 10 minutes
if (sleeptime < 120) sleeptime = sleeptime + 600; // skip if next round 10 minutes is less than 2 minutes away
esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(1000000 * sleeptime);
esp_deep_sleep_start();
```

The code works correctly in > 99.5% of the cases, but occasionally ESP32 only goes into sleep mode for at most a few seconds, although the minimum sleep time should be at least 120s according to the code. There must be something wrong with this code and I can not figure out what. One of the reasons is that the device is not connected to the USB and I can not read the serial communication.

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You are overthinking it, if it needs to wake up every 10 minutes, then all you need to do is `esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(10*60e6);`, 10 is the number of minutes, and 60e6 is 60 x 1000000 (i.e. 1 minute or 60 seconds).

Comment: @hcheung I want the measurements to be as close to round 10 minutes as possible, and with your method the time would drift away from that very quickly.

Comment: You should give additional details about your goal here. Provide a few examples as well.

Comment: @thepirat000 I already provided the explanation and the code.  Could you kindly explain what additional details are missing?  What examples are you having in your mind?